# Raspbian wheezyでPython2.7.3から2.7.10にアップデートしたらsmbusをimportできなくなった

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

お世話になります。
下記手順でRaspbian wheezyのPython2.7.3を2.7.10にアップデートしました

```
wget -c https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tgz
tar -xzvf Python-2.7.10.tgz
cd Python-2.7.10/
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

アップデート後、2.3.7で正常に動作していた.pyファイルを実行したら、Pythonがsmbusが見つからないとエラーを吐くようになりました。再度

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libi2c-dev i2c-tools python-dev libffi-dev
pip install cffi
pip install smbus-cffi
```

上記手順でsmbusモジュールのインストールを試みましたが、やはりPythonはsmbusが見つからないとエラーを吐きます。
どうしたら正常にPythonにsmbusを認識したもらえるようになるでしょうか？
アドバイスをよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `./configure` に `--prefix` オプションが付いていませんので、おそらく `/usr/local` ディレクトリ以下にインストールされていると思います。そのため、python2.7.10 で使うモジュールは `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` にインストールする必要があるのではないでしょうか。ただ、環境変数 `PYTHONHOME` か `PYTHONPATH` を設定すれば `/usr/lib/python2.7`(ｐython2.7.3のモジュールディレクトリ)にあるモジュールを参照することができるかと思います。

Comment: @argus
`LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" ./configure --prefix /usr/local/lib/python2.7`
`make`
`sudo make install`
上記を実行しましたが、pythonと入力しても2.7.3のままです。どうしたら2.7.10をsmbusを認識できる形でインストールできるのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`python-smbus` を apt でインストールすると, Raspbian 標準の Python 2.7 から smbus を利用できるようになります.

apt でインストールした smbus モジュールは `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smbus.so` にインストールされるため, 別途インストールした Python 2.7.10 からはそのままでは利用できないはずです.

apt でインストールした `smbus.so` を 別途インストールした Python から使うには, いくつかの方法が考えられます.

1. `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smbus.so` から `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smbus.so` にシンボリックリンクを貼る.
2. `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smbus.so` を `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smbus.so` にコピーする.
3. `PYTHONPATH` に `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` を追加する.

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。